# can not deploy web service via endpoint.publish() in apache reverse proxy env

Tags: ssl, proxy, weblogic, jax-ws

we have a weblogic server in the internal network without SSL. To access the application, apache server is installed as a reverse proxy and also have configure SSL. it is ok to deploy web service via endpoint.publish(address) that address is get from httpservletrequest.getRequestURL() if the access url is internal. But failed and throw the below exception if the access url is proxy url. Any idea to publish it via proxy url?

```
weblogic.wsee.server.ServerURLNotFoundException: Cannot resolve URL for protocol http/https
at weblogic.wsee.server.ServerUtil.getHTTPServerURL(ServerUtil.java:211)
at weblogic.wsee.server.ServerUtil.getServerURL(ServerUtil.java:150)
at weblogic.wsee.server.ServerUtil.getServerURL(ServerUtil.java:137)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSEndpoint.calculatePublicAddressFromEndpointAddress(WLSEndpoint.java:335)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSEndpoint.publish(WLSEndpoint.java:207)
```

Comment: I debug the code and noticed the address is 'https://proxy/app/ws?wsdl' when doing endpoint.publish(address). Then, I tried to modify the url and use http instead of https. It works. Even if the proxy serve and weblogic server are in different machine, it still work.  What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

As per Oracle KM: Secure WebService call throwing CANNOT RESOLVE URL FOR PROTOCOL HTTP/HTTPS through web server(APACHE) plug-in. (Doc ID 1598617.1)

This is a Product Bug 8358398. For wls 10.3.0 to 10.3.2 you need to apply patch for this BUG and set `-Dweblogic.wsee.useRequestHost=true`

Blockquote

in your JAVA_OPTIONS.

For 10.3.3 and above version you need not to apply the patch. You can only set the above flag to true.

Comment: I tried to add  it to java_options when starting weblogic. And my weblogic version is 12.1.3.0.0. However, it does not work and still have the error   weblogic.wsee.server.ServerURLNotFoundException.